# Struct returned from C++ DLL missing first element in array data

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll, unmanaged

I have a Unity5 program that is using a common structure (**smMsg**) to send data from a C++ DLL into C#.

The structure contains an array:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] mtx;
```

This array is to be considered as a 4x4 Matrix, hence the constant size of 16.

---

The program works, receiving data into the C# corresponding structure; however, it seems that from my array I am missing the **first** element (mtx[0]) each time I run the program. It seems every other element has shifted to the left with an extra `0` for the last element, maintaining the sequential order they are to be in.

I considered it to be because of the `UnmanagedType` I was using, however other sources tell me that `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` is the correct type.

Would anyone have a direction or lead I can follow to help solve this problem?

---

**Process of Copying Data**

C#:

```
// DLL Import
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "smCopy")] 
private static extern void smCopyData(IntPtr dest, IntPtr len); //const VOID *dest, SIZE_T len);

// Copying data logic
{
    //  allocate intptr to buffer
    var len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(smMsg));
    IntPtr msg_intptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len); 

    try
    {
        //  Copy data
        smCopyData(msg_intptr, (IntPtr)(len));

        //  Set POINTER data to struct
        return_msg = (smMsg)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg_intptr, typeof(smMsg));

    }
    finally
    {
        //  free unmanaged memory!
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msg_intptr);
    }
}
```

C++

```
// Function called via DLL
void DLL_API smCopy(const VOID *dest, SIZE_T len)
{
    CopyMemory((PVOID)(dest), (PVOID)(mapBuffer), len);
}
```

---

**Struct Definition**

The main piece of data I am interested in is `float[] mtx`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct smMsg 
{
   public smHeader header;
   public smData data; 
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct smData
{
   // Event ID.
   public int evtId;
   public int status;

   // Floating point values. Actual data to be transmitted.
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
   public float[] mtx; 
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct smHeader
{
   public ushort chkSum;
   public char numWords;
   public char msgType;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2/29**

Thanks to @Zastai, I ended up able to recover the missing element. As it turns out, I wanted to be using "byte" as the data type instead of char, as char is a C# unicode type (short).

What I ended up doing is changing my smHeader as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct smHeader   
{
   public ushort chkSum; 

   public byte numWords;

   public byte msgType;
}
```

.. which in turn lowered the smHeader size from 6 to 4, setting the smMsg struct size equal in terms of both C# & C++.

Comment: what's definition of the struct? The problem might be in the structure layout

Comment: smMsg is made of two other structs: smHeader & smData;; smData contains 2 int(s) & the float[] mtx variable. I can edit the question above to show actual code.

Comment: That looks fine at first glance. To verify: get Marshal.SizeOf for the three structs (header/data/msg), and do the same with sizeof in C. That will show you whether you made a mistake with the struct contents. Side note: I would not be inclined to use IntPtr for non-pointer arguments; but it's not wrong either.

Comment: Also, why would you use `const void*` for the destination parameter in C++?? It's clearly not const (you even cast away the constness)...

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but it's likely in the marshaling. I know that the memory layout of an int array contains an additional 0 value after the array contents; likely the data is off-by-one.

Comment: @Zastai I did what you suggested and got the sizes for each of the structs. In C# smMsg added up to 80, while in C++ smMsg added up to 76; smHead in C# is 6 & in C++ is 4. I'm guessing that's where that first element was misplaced or destroyed?

Comment: Chances are there's struct padding involved. StructLayoutAttribute has a parameter for that. Try setting the padding to 0 for all 3 structs.

Comment: @Zastai No luck, the data is still shifted. I experimented with the other Pack sizes, and it definitely only works if the Pack default size is set (so not 1 or 2 as Pack).

Comment: What I noticed now however is that smMsg.size=80 in C#, yet it's variables are sizes 6(smHead) & 72(smData), so there are 2 bytes unaccounted for.

Comment: As a last resort, you could add offset attributes to the struct fields, but that would not magically shrink the header struct, so you may need to combine the header & data fields in smMsg (instead of putting the structs themselves). It's weird though. I don't suppose decompiling the assembly with ILSpy or the like shows anything that points to what extra fields are being added?

Comment: Oh so smData is 72 in C#? That seems correct. Could you add your smHeader struct to the question too?

Comment: As for the 2 bytes, that's struct padding - turning the 6 into 8. It sounds like if you can fix the header to be size 4 like in C++, it'll all start working.

Comment: @Zastai can do, the question was updated. The smHeader only contains a couple of chars and unsigned short. It's data that's used for the server mostly, not so much for my own use. Also I just wanted to say now, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Try either setting the padding to 0 for the header, or adding FieldOffset attributes to its 3 fields (offsets 0, 2 and 3, respectively).

Comment: @Zastai I don't know what to say, but thank you!! I tried setting the offsets to 0, 2, 3, and that didn't work; I don't know if you meant to say offsets 0, 1, 2, respectively, or not, because that's what ended up recovering the first element! I'll answer the question with a more detailed report on what happened, but thanks again!

Comment: No, I meant 0, 2 and 3. If you put the ushort at 0 and the first char at 1, they overlap. Which reminds me what the issue really was: a C# char is a unicode character, so a short. You want byte or sbyte, not char, for the last two fields.

Comment: @Zastai Yup, that worked as well! Thank you very much helping me resolve this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zastai for helping out a ton.

Turns out that when using **char** in C++ for a struct, it's C# counterpart is a **byte**. This resolved the difference in structure size between C# & C++. Because of this error, the smMsg struct in C# allocated more memory than it needed.

The question is updated with the new smHeader definition.